# how can I hide an argument on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now my code is going to hide index.html but I want to hide highlighted.html as well. I've tried to add + 'highlighted.html' but it doesn't work.

like this `if (fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'index.html' + 'highlighted.html'){`

```
if ( fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls.length > 0 ) {
for(var i=0; i < fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls.length; i++) {
    if (fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'index.html'){
    nextOneSelectorHtml += 
      '<option ' + 
        'class="html-page-option" ' + 
        'data-html-page-name="' + fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] + '">' + 
          fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] + 
      '</option>';
    }else{playSwf( strPath+'/index.html');}
}
}
```

Now my code looks like this:

but if I try to use this line twice then it will not load the html anymore and the only thing I want is to hide them.

Here I could hide both but I still can see the highlighted.html from the second argument.

`if (fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'highlighted.html' && fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'index.html'){`

```
if ( fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls.length > 0 ) {
    for(var i=0; i < fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls.length; i++) {
        if (fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'highlighted.html' && fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'index.html'){
        nextOneSelectorHtml += 
          '<option ' + 
            'class="html-page-option" ' + 
            'data-html-page-name="' + fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] + '">' + 
              fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] + 
          '</option>';
        }else{high( strPath+'/highlighted.html');}
    }
  }

  if ( fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls.length > 0 ) {
    for(var i=0; i < fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls.length; i++) {
        if (fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'index.html'){
        nextOneSelectorHtml += 
          '<option ' + 
            'class="html-page-option" ' + 
            'data-html-page-name="' + fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] + '">' + 
              fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] + 
          '</option>';
        }else{playSwf( strPath+'/index.html');}
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does happen when it "doesn't work"?  Error, or behaviour you didn't want, or what?

Comment: Its just doing nothing

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this code is supposed to work, but for the AND logical operation in the `if` clause, you should use the `&&` operator:

```
if (fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'index.html'
   && fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'highlighted.html') {
   ...
```

The above means "if the value is not 'index.html' AND it's not 'highlighted.html'".

To make it a bit more readable - since you'd be using the file name twice, you could introduce a helper variable:

```
var fileName = fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i];
if (fileName != 'index.html' && fileName != 'highlighted.html') {
  ...
```

---

The reason the `+` operator you tried to use didn't work, is that it would concatenate two strings and then compare them with the value. So:

```
if (fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'index.html' + 'highlighted.html'){
```

has same effect as:

```
if (fsStructure[strPath].subshtmls[i] != 'index.htmlhighlighted.html'){
```

Comment: but I don't want to use or operator i want to use something like and or + I want to hide both files

Comment: With an AND clause (the `&&` operator) you can logically say "I don't want the file name to be 'index.html' and I don't want it to be 'highlighted.html'" - this is what you're trying to achieve, right? While currently using the `+` operator, you're saying "I don't want file name to be 'index.htmlhighlighted.html'" (see updated answer).